# Setting a src value into an iframe

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to set a `src` value into a Backbone View with an element of iFrame. This `src` value comes from the Model but it doesn't render properly. It returns `Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.` How can I get this to work? Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

app.js

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        url: 'https://www.w3schools.com'
    }
});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '<iframe src="<%= url %>"></iframe>',

    initialize: function () {
        this.render()
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html( this.model.get('url') );
    }
});


var person = new Person;
var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });

$(document.body).append(personView.el);
```

It works only when I do in the console:

```
var btn = document.createElement("iframe");
btn.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com';
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Yes. I'm using a tutorial to learn. But I have read the documentation as well. I'm sure the answer of this question will answer more than one thing, that could help more people who are in a similar situation as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is your view's `el`:

```
el: '<iframe src="<%= url %>"></iframe>'
```

The [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) is supposed to be a DOM selector string or a DOM node. Your HTML snippet is neither of those. Also, Underscore template markup (i.e. `<%= url %>`) won't be evaluated in `el` since `el` isn't a template.

Your second problem is that your `render`:

```
this.$el.html( this.model.get('url') );
```

is trying to set the *content* of your view's `el` to the value of the model's `url` attribute and trying to set the content of an `iframe` doesn't do anything useful. Normally you'd say something more like this in a `render`:

```
var tmpl = _.template(some_template_string);
this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
return this;
```

`this.model.toJSON()` usually returns an object of key/value pairs and that's what a compiled Underscore template wants to see.

In your case, you don't even need your own `render` implementation, you can do it all by properly building your `el`. If you check the documentation for `View#el`, you'll see this:

> `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties.

You want a `tagName` of `iframe` and `{ src: the_url_from_the_model }` for `attributes` so your view becomes just this:

```
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'iframe',
    attributes: function() {
        return {
            src: this.model.get('url')
        };
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4t248ejp/